# Div inside another Div positioned relatively and overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a parent Div positioned relatively and is set to `overflow:hidden`. How do I overlay the Div inside?

I set the margin of the inner div to negative because I want it to overlap with the parent div.

**html**

```
<div class="out">
   <div class="in">
   </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.out{
   margin-left:100px;
   width:130px;
   height:130px;  
   margin-top:10px;
   border:1px solid blue;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}

.in{
   width:80px;
   height:80px;
   z-index: 999;
   clear: both;
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -20px;
   margin-top: -20px;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of how you want it to display?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
position:absolute 
z-index:9999;
```

You can position an overlay inside of your div

Remember to set your parent div with the position:relative property and a lower z-index

Answer (score 0):

Made the following changes to your `.in` CSS,

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

removed the following lines,

```
margin-left: -20px;
margin-top: -20px;
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/KkAdE/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I need the inner div to overlap with the outer div that's why I set the margin-left & margin-top to negative.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what the end result should look like